# Implementing Clarifai API

Tags: java, android, clarifai

I need some help with connecting hte `Clarifai` API into my android app. It's for a uni project where we tests different image recognition softwares. All it needs to do is take a picture on the phone and then run recognition on the `pituces` (which will be buildings).

I have no idea how to do this which is why i'm throwing this hail mary in the hope that someone would help me. I've put what i have in a drive here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1LH79C0JtpBBpAMdKqNjKfYfj3KTvLgAh?usp=sharing

How can I solve this?

Comment: https://clarifai.com/developer/guide/android-sdk#predict-on-device

Answer (score 0):

To use the Clarifai API on Android, you should use the [Clarifai API Java client](https://github.com/Clarifai/clarifai-java). Alternatively, if you wish not to install the library, you can do REST and execute HTTP requests directly using JSON. See [the developer's guide](https://www.clarifai.com/developer/guide/) for examples.

Note: There's also an Android SDK in works, which is beta at the time of this writing. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53601088/365837) on how to join the beta program.