# How to get the Clarifai' Android SDK?

Tags: android, image-recognition, clarifai

I want to build a simple application to where I use Clarifai's Image recognition feature without an internet connection. 
But according to Clarifai's documentation, Clarifai's Android SDK is still in a private beta version and we need to request them to get it. But they did not reply me. Is there any other way I can get it? 
My main objective is to develop a simple application to demonstrate the use of Clarifai's Image recognition feature without an internet connection using their Android SDK. Is there a way I can do that? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please send an email to android-sdk@clarifai.com with your name, email, and use case.

We will be glad to accommodate you in the beta program.

Comment: I send an email to android-sdk@clarifai.com. Please check it. I need it bit urgently.